# one contoller file adding to another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here i am trying to add one page controller adding to another controller using same module in angular js. how can i add ctrl2.js menu to inside ctrl1.js.please help me currently i am using angualrjs one .. i am struck in this issue please give me a solution ...

**menu.html:**

```
    <div id="left-top" ng-controller="two">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu-top-left col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <li>
                <a href="#/">
                    <i class="material-icons mobile-menu-icon-color">exit_to_app</i>
                    <span class="notification mobile-menu-icon-color">Logout</span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="material-icons mobile-menu-icon-color">person</i>
                    <span class="notification mobile-menu-icon-color">{{name}}</span>
                </a>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

**ctrl1.js**

```
            var app=angular.module('board',[]);
            app.controller('one',function($scope){

            alert("ctrlone');
            });
```

**ctrl2.js**

```
            var app=angular.module('board',[]);
            app.controller('two',function($scope){

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
          <div ng-controller="secondController"></div>
</div>
```

if you want to use common $scope(your data) for ctrl1 and ctrl2, you need to create service for this, and after inject service to ctrl1, and ctrl2

Comment: var app=angular.module('board',[]); -> this line init only once

Comment: for create service you can to look angularjs patterns